# How to get and save values from otpions page on chrome extension and pass them to background.js

Tags: javascript, html, dom, google-chrome-extension

I have just built my very simple options page for my extension.
I'm now looking into ways to extract data from it and feed it to the background.js file so it can act according to the options specified in the options page.
I have a slider, a list and an on/off switch in the options page.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Tab Manager | Options Page</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <div>
      <strong>LOGO + TabManager</strong>
    </div>
    <!--TO DO: add logo and text at the top left corner-->
    <section>
      <div>
          <img src="Graphics/Images/gear icon.png" width="100">
          <h1>General Options</h1>
      </div>
    </section>
  </head>
  <body>
    <section>
      <div class="slidecontainer">
        <h2>Managing Level&lt;&gt; 
        <input type="range" min="1" max="3" value="50" class="slider" id="myRange"></h2>
        <!--TO DO: change pic to slider-->
      </div>
      <div>
        <h2>White List &lt;&gt; (  ,  )</h2>
      </div>
      <div>
        <h2>Allow server to collect data &lt;&gt; 
        <input type="checkbox"> </h2>
      </div>
    </section>
  </body>
</html>
```

I want to get the values from the range slider and the on and off swithces on top of addding values to the list.
In addition to that I'm new to js, html and chrome extensions so any feedback would be great.

Comment: use chrome.storage to save those values and retrieve wherever you need (background).

Comment: how do i get the values from the options page, i tired to use dom from backgorund.js to get the slider but no avail

Comment: First you have to save these values. The best choice to save option vars is chrome.storage (local or sync). If you are working on MV2 extension you could use also localStorage vars. But I strongly suggest you to opt for the first one. See docs here: https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/storage/